# Lucene SpellCheck Doesn't Index 2 Letter Words

Tags: java, lucene, spell-checking

I'm using Lucene for spellcheck operation. But it doesn't index 2 letter words. It seems a common problem about Lucene spellcheck.

This is my index method:

```
    String fileName = "words.txt";

    Dictionary dictionary = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)), "UTF-8"));
        dictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(bufferedReader);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    SpellChecker spell = null;
    try {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(spellCheckerPath);
        spell = new SpellChecker(directory);
        spell .setAccuracy(0.5f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_2, new StandardAnalyzer());
    indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
    try {
        spell.indexDictionary(dictionary, indexWriterConfig, true);
        spell.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, this method works for 3 or more letter words. But, it can't index 2 letter words. I read about stopWords. I tried to give empty StopWords to StandardAnalyzer as parameter; but it didnn't work. (Also, I tried to search with Luke, it can't find it)

I need to use 4.10.2 version of Lucene. I appreciate any help.

Comment: please try accuracy `0.3f` instead of `0.5f` because for a 2letter word the change off one letter is a change of 50%.

Comment: I tried but there is no result for 2 letter words. (I checked the results from Luke too)

Comment: @bodoroman did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ArunGowda Did you try using `setMinPrefix(1)` and `setMinQueryLength(2)` ?

Comment: @EricLavault where do I set this? Im doing a exists query on spellchecker dictionary. Iam not setting it explicitly anywhere. Is it 2 by default?

Comment: @EricLavault The suggested methods are available in `DirectSpellChecker` and not `SpellChecker`, which I am currently using. Do you happen to know how they are different? I don't mind changing my code to use `DirectSpellChecker`. But I want to know how it is different. Also, the documentation says: **WARNING: This API is experimental and might change in incompatible ways in the next release.** https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/DirectSpellChecker.html

Comment: @EricLavault `setMinPrefix` is 1 by default. Sets the minimal number of initial characters (default: 1) that must match exactly.

Comment: DirectSpellChecker loads candidates directly from a term dictionary, whereas standard SpellChecker needs an index dictionary (eg. LuceneDictionary, PlainTextDictionary). Yes `setMinPrefix` defaults to 1, but you need `setMinQueryLength(2)` to trigger spellcheck and load suggestions with 2 or more letter words. In case you don't want to switch to DirectSpellChecker, you need to use NGramTokenizer with `minGram=1` for your index dictionary. Since you are building your index dictionary from a file, you can just as well use that file with DirectSpellChecker.